# Displaying values of Array. Getting strange values

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I would like to make k random points of type TockaXY.
TockaXY is defined:

```
 public static class TockaXY {

      private float x;
      private float y;

      public TockaXY(float x, float y) { 
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;  
      }
```

The function is like this:

```
 public static TockaXY[] randomCentri(int k, int lowerBound, int upperBound) {
       TockaXY[] arrayCentri = new TockaXY[k];
          for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
              float x = (float)(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound)/100;
              float y = (float)(Math.random() * (upperBound - lowerBound) + lowerBound)/100;
              TockaXY point = new TockaXY(x, y);
              arrayCentri[i]=point;
          }
          System.out.println(" Random centri: " + arrayCentri);
          return arrayCentri;

      }
```

But I get:

```
Random centri: [LTest$TockaXY;@6ce253f1
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a toString method in your `TockaXY` class

```
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return "TockaXY{" + "x=" + x + ", y=" + y + '}';
}
```

and use Array.toString while printing

```
System.out.println(" Random centri: " + Arrays.toString(arrayCentri));
```

or use a loop to print each array element

```
for(TockaXY point: arrayCentri){
    System.out.println(point);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you only see a representation of the pointer. Java internally will call .toString() on `String + Object`.

Implement a toString() method in your `TockaXY` class and iterate over the array, transforming every entry of the array to String.